# How can I use Java Reflection in this application

Tags: java, reflection

I want to use Reflection API in my Application .
I have a Interface  and its implementation class , with all the Method declartions as shown .

Please let me know how can i Use Reflection for the above code .

I have started writing client class , but i am not sure if this is right or not ?? Please let me know how can i invoke the method

Please help me in

```
public interface DataHandler extends Remote {

    public abstract String logon(String  message) throws RemoteException;
    public abstract String logoff(String message) throws RemoteException;
    public abstract String userinformation(String message) throws RemoteException;
    public abstract String updateUser(String message) throws RemoteException; 
}
```

**And an implementation class for the above interface as shown**

```
public class CodeHandler implements DataHandler
{
    public  String logon(String  message) throws RemoteException {}
    public  String logoff(String  message) throws RemoteException {}
    public  String userinformation(String  message) throws RemoteException {}
    public  String updateUser(String  message) throws RemoteException {}
}
```

**I have a client class as shown**

```
public class Client
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        callMethod("logon"); 
    }

    private Object callMethod(String  message) {
        String methodName = message ;
        Method method = DataHandler.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, null);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        // How to use method.invoke in this case ??
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to use Reflection, or to accomplish something using Reflection? If so, what?

Comment: Thanks , I want to get the logon method of CodeHandler  gets called .

Comment: Then create an Object of type CodeHandler and call the logon method with this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that your interface extends `java.rmi.Remote`, so I guess you have to use the RMI facility instead of reflection here, but if you *really* need to use reflection try something like this:

```
private Object callMethod(CodeHandler codeHandler, String methodName, String message) {
    try {
        Method method = DataHandler.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, String.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);

        return method.invoke(codeHandler, message);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        handle(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        handle(e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        handle(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, gave you a mention in mine.

Comment: Hi , could you please let me know about the second argument you passed to getDeclaredMethod ?? (String.class ) . The documentation is confusion . Please anybody let me know

Comment: A Java class may have multiple methods with the same name, but different parameters types. So in order to uniquely identify a method you have to provide both its name *and* parameters types. Now all your four methods take a single parameter of type `String`.

Comment: So in case if my logon  Method accepts an Object as a arguement i need to do this way 
DataHandler.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, Object );
Am i correct ??

Comment: Thanks Saintali , i got it what you were trying to tell . Thanks a lot once again .

Comment: Actually `DataHandler.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, Object.class)`, and if it takes two params, an `int` and an `Object`, you would say `DataHandler.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, int.class, Object.class)` etc. My pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   private Object callMethod(String methodName, CodeHandler object, String strParamForMethod)
   {
      try
      {
         Method method = DataHandler.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, null);
         method.setAccessible(true);
         method.invoke(object, strParamForMethod);
      }
      catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e)
      {
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks , what will be the value for strParam ?? while making a call to this method ?

Comment: methodName - is method's name, strParamForMethod - is parameter that you want pass to this method

Answer (score 1):

logon(String message) is an instance method in your example; you cannot invoke it without first creating an instance of CodeHandler (see Saintali's answer for how).  If you declare the method to be static, then you can invoke it via:

```
method.invoke(null, message);
```

See the [Method API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for more details.

Comment: `null` only for static methods

Comment: I explictly stated that in my answer.  There are more to answers than just the code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mentioned that you just want to call the method logon in the class CodeHandler. So you should no use reflection but do it like this:

```
public class Client {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      callMethod("logon"); 
   }

   private Object callMethod(String  message) {
      CodeHandler codeHandler = new CodeHandler();
      codeHandler.logon(message);
   }
}
```